# loading you script file at end of content load angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following script:-

```
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function (eve,uri) {
        var js = document.createElement("script");
        js.type = "text/javascript";
        js.src = '/assets/js/scripts.js';
        document.body.appendChild(js);
    });
```

but this appends the script the number of times i have used ng-include in my app. What is the way to include script after the entire page is laoded.

Comment: That is because `$includeContentLoaded` callback is firing whenever the template is included in the entire application. You could check the callback values `eve` and `uri` and insert the script only it matches

Comment: What does you mean by **lazyload**. You are already doing the same?

Comment: you can assign an id to the script tag being inserted, and check if it is already appended to body

Comment: yes right but there are multiple views which depends on the script, so i cant use comparison. is there any other solution like oclazyload

Comment: @monish can you explain how

Comment: js.setAttribute('id', 'myScript');

var oldJs = document.body.getElementById('myScript');
if(oldJs==null){
 document.body.appendChild(js);
}

Comment: instantiate the js var inside the if block. The if will still be evaulated everytime include is called though

Comment: @monish not working

Comment: can you provide more information. Is the id not assigned to the script tag? is the if condition not working? is the getElementById not working? @DHRUVGUPTA

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA can you confirm whether you want to load the above script **one time**

Comment: yes @GangadharJannu I want to load one time

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42226194/3543808)

Answer (score 0):

Add a check before you add the script.

```
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function (eve, uri) {
    if(!document.querySelectorAll("script[src*='assets/js/scripts.js']").length){
        var js = document.createElement("script");
        js.type = "text/javascript";
        js.src = '/assets/js/scripts.js';
        document.body.appendChild(js);
    }
});
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/vyygv1w5/1/) I've implemented the similar behavior and it is absolutely working fine.